# Add Forms from another project in Borland C++

Tags: project, borland-c++

I'm currently working on a project using Borland C++, I have two Forms so far but each one in an independent Project, I wish to join these two project into one project so I can switch between the Forms.

I want to have only one executable file (for security purposes), I tried reading some pdfs about borland c++, also tried googling it, but no luck.

if there's a way to do so, I wish you could guide me or give me some hints.

Note: I'm using Borland C++ Builder 6, under Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

I am used to BDS2006 so for newer IDE/Compilers it can be different

1.form copy

- has *.h,*.cpp,*.dfm files
- copy them to target project directory

2.open target project in IDE

3.add forms to project

- find add to project in IDE main menu (I think it is in Project tag)
- then select *.dfm files of your new forms click add or OK ...

4.Open target project source code (*.cpp)

should look like this:

```
//$$---- EXE CPP ----
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//*** here you have line for each form type and its name in forms menu
USEFORM("win_view.cpp", win_view);
USEFORM("win_main.cpp", win_main);
USEFORM("win_editor\win_editor_setup.cpp", win_EditorSetup);
USEFORM("win_editor\win_editor.cpp", win_editor);
USEFORM("win_editor\win_editor_find.cpp", win_EditorFind);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
    try
    {
        Application->Initialize();
        //*** here create form for each static form you want
        //*** dynamic windows (created in runtime are not here !!!
        Application->CreateForm(__classid(Twin_main), &win_main);
        //*** here load cross references to forms if needed
        Application->Run();
    }
    catch (Exception &exception)
    {
        Application->ShowException(&exception);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        try
        {
            throw Exception("");
        }
        catch (Exception &exception)
        {
            Application->ShowException(&exception);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

5.dynamic forms

- add #include of *.h for all dynamic/used inside form files to main form cpp file
- this makes them accessible from main form
- now you can crete / destroy windows

should look like this:

```
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #include <vcl.h>
    #pragma hdrstop
    #include "win_main.h"
    //*** add the dynamic/used forms *.h files
    #include "win_view.h"
    #include "win_editor\win_editor.h"
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //*** add pointer to dynamic forms
    Twin_view       *win_view=NULL;
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void __fastcall Twin_main::some_event(...)
        {
        win_view=new Twin_view(win_main);
        if (win_view)
            {
            win_view->OnResize(win_view);
            win_view->_can_close=false;
            }
        }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void __fastcall Twin_main::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
        {
        //*** destroy form before exiting also can call ->Close() and wait few [ms]  before
        if (win_view) { delete win_view; win_view=NULL; }
        }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- you can also move the form pointers to owner form class to make it more objective c++ like
- and allow to make multiple originaly main forms in future (in another project later)

6.static used forms

- just include *.cpp file instead of *.h
- the pointer to these forms are directly in *.cpp files (at the start)

[notes]

- if your forms have some global variables
- then you can not use more then 1 form of that type
- also the global variable names have to be different between used forms
- do not change namespace for them it will make VCL crazy